# Expose/deploy more than a single handler (quarkus-lambda)

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus

The [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda) shows that the exposed handler (via `io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest` in the packaged application) is configured by setting `quarkus.lambda.handler` in `application.properties`. However in my case I'd like to deploy multiple handlers from the same project.

Does anyone know of a way, or whether it's possible, to expose more than a single handler from a quarkus-lambda project?

Edit: After reading through https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/amazon-lambda/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/amazon/lambda/runtime/AmazonLambdaRecorder.java#L89 it seems that this is indeed not possible right now, is that correct?

Comment: The Quarkus lambda handler is just an entrypoint for the AWS lambda runtime to enter your application. Past that point, what you do is completely up to you. So you don't really need multiple Quarkus lambda handlers. All you need is one handler for you to be able to receive Lambda events. You can then use the contextual information from the Lambda to route the processing elsewhere inside your application, combined with a pattern like Command or Strategy. Is there a hard reason you must have multiple lambda handlers?

Comment: I realize I _can_ do that, however our current strategy has been to leverage API gateway integration towards out lambdas using the NodeJS runtime. So say I have a `GET` on `/pets/{id}`, and a `POST` on `/pets` in the API gateway, then these would integrate both with different handlers in the same deployment.

The upside is that we can use LPP on the lambdas, we can use different IAM policies per endpoint, etc, while still using a shared codebase per service. I think using the "monolambda" approach you're describing means we'd have to give up at least some of that.

Comment: Right re:giving up granular access control. Otherwise, you'll need to slim down your Quarkus app to be a true micro service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now possible by setting the `QUARKUS_LAMBDA_HANDLER` environment variable for each lambda function. This environment variable will override `quarkus.lambda.handler` in `application.properties`.

For instance, if you have multiple handlers defined as so:

```java
    @Named("Test")
    public class TestLambda implements RequestHandler<InputObject, OutputObject> {

        @Inject
        ProcessingService service;

        @Override
        public OutputObject handleRequest(InputObject input, Context context) {
            return new OutputObject().setRequestId("1").setResult("Test");
        }

    }

    @Named("Sample")
    public class SampleLambda implements RequestHandler<InputObject, OutputObject> {

        @Inject
        ProcessingService service;

        @Override
        public OutputObject handleRequest(InputObject input, Context context) {
            return new OutputObject().setRequestId("2").setResult("Sample");
        }
    }
```

You could build the single project and deploy multiple functions with the following SAM template.

```json
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    Description: AWS Serverless Quarkus - quarkus-amazon-lambda-common-deployment
    Globals:
      Api:
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        BinaryMediaTypes:
          - "*/*"

    Resources:

      TestFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          Handler: io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest
          Runtime: java11
          CodeUri: target/function.zip
          MemorySize: 256
          Timeout: 15
          Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
          Environment:
            Variables:
              QUARKUS_LAMBDA_HANDLER: Test
          Events:
            TestFunction:
              Type: Api
              Properties:
                Path: /test
                Method: get


      SampleFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          Handler: io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest
          Runtime: java11
          CodeUri: target/function.zip
          MemorySize: 256
          Timeout: 15
          Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
          Environment:
            Variables:
              QUARKUS_LAMBDA_HANDLER: Sample
          Events:
            HelloWorld:
              Type: Api
              Properties:
                Path: /sample
                Method: get
```

Comment: This throws errors while running mvn quarkus:dev

Answer (score 1):

You should just write a RestEasy Resource and then follow the steps written here:

https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http

For a full example with RestEasy & DynamoDB, read these:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/dynamodb
- https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http

Basically, the idea is that you just write Rest Resources in Quarkus and Quarkus deploys & configures all your Resource endpoints as Api-Gateways and Lambda's & Handlers in AWS via the SAM CLI.

Make sure you have these 2 dependencies in your classpath:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then run:

```
mvn clean install
```

To make sure that the necessary artifacts are created in your /target folder.

Comment: The thing with this approach is, that it will use the "monolambda" pattern to support these multiple endpoints. Basically it boils down to a single API Gateway endpoint proxying everything to the quarkus microservice. However, this is not wanted for our usecase for a variety of reasons, following least-privilege-principle for our handlers being one of the more important ones.

Comment: What about writing "mini monolamda's" that have the same permissions and security restrictions together ?